# Where do I add initialisation code in a class library?

Tags: c#, valueinjecter

I've got a class library that users the [ValueInjecter](https://github.com/omuleanu/ValueInjecter) library. In some cases, I need to create custom maps and I'm not sure where I need to put the call(s) to `Mapper.AddMap()`.

If I was using this in an application with a main entry point I could do something like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    InitialiseMappings();
}

void InitialiseMappings()
{
    Mapper.AddMap<TypeA, TypeB>(src = > { 
        // Mapping code... 
    });

    Mapper.AddMap<TypeC, TypeD>(src = > { 
        // Mapping code... 
    });

    // etc.
}
```

In a class library, there doesn't appear to be a straightforward way to run 'initialisation' code, so I'm not sure how to approach this. The code can't be called multiple times as trying to add duplicate/identical mappings throws an exception.

Where should I put the code to create these maps?

Comment: In the static constructor of the class that consumes the maps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it in a [static constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx).

```
public class SomeClass {
    static SomeClass() {
        InitialiseMappings();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do I do if that map is used in multiple classes?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. The code in the static constructor is run once. Create your mappings once in that place.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I'm asking what do I do if a particular mapping is used in two different classes since I can't create it twice.

Comment: You could call a static method in class A from the static constructor of class B. That way one triggers the other if the other hasn't run yet.